# Is scipy's euler and rotvec the same thing?

Tags: python, numpy, math, image-processing, scipy

Does `scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation` 's `rotvec` and `euler` do the same thing ? If not, how are they different ?

Comment: what happened when you tried reading the documentation?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Documentation induces violent urge to post on SO. Can confirm :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What are `scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation`, `...rotvec` and `...euler`?

Well the documentation of `..Rotation` pretty much says it

> This class [] provides an interface to initialize from and represent
> rotations with:
>
> - Quaternions
> - Rotation Matrices
> - Rotation Vectors
> - Modified Rodrigues Parameters
> - Euler Angles
>
> See
> https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.html

So `scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation` is a generalized interface for rotations. There are those five ways of representing rotations including `rotvec` and `euler`. You can give a rotation in any of them using e.g. `scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.from_euler`. And once you have a rotation you can transform it to any of those representations using e.g. scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.as_rotvec.

#### Why have such an interface?

The advantage of transforming a particular rotation to this generalized one is clear. You can convert between them and do things you usually wanna do with rotations. From the `Rotation` docs again

> The following operations on rotations are supported:
>
> - Application on vectors
> - Rotation Composition
> - Rotation Inversion
> - Rotation Indexing